# How to animate sprite from plist file

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, cocos2d-html5

I'm new to Cocos2d and I have problem with animations in **Cocos2d-HTML5**.

Below is my sprite's constructor function.
I've generated `plist` file with **TexturePacker**.
I would like to play animation and repeat it infinitely. I was able to play it once by creating animation in following way:

```
var animation = new cc.Animation(frames, 0.2);
```

But when I pass loops count as a third parameter I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Class> has no method 'getDelayUnits'`

```
ctor: function (position) {
    this._super();

    var cache = cc.SpriteFrameCache.getInstance();
    cache.addSpriteFrames(s_dogList, s_Dog);

    var frames = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.NUMBER_OF_FRAMES; i++) {
        var spriteFrame = cache.getSpriteFrame('dog' + i + '.png');
        frames.push(spriteFrame);
    };
    this.initWithSpriteFrame(frames[0]);

    var animation = cc.Animation.create(frames, 0.2, 100);
    var animate = cc.Animate.create(animation);
    this.runAction(animate);
}
```

I've investigated the code and I see that when creating animation with 3 parameters (with `loops` parameter) it needs each frame to be instance of the `AnimationFrame` class. But when I pass only 2 parameters, frames have to be instances of the `SpriteFrame` class. How to creat animation using `AnimationFrame` and repeat it infinitely?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the solution. To repeat given animation forever there is special type of action `cc.RepeatForever`. You just write like this:

```
var animation = cc.Animation.create(frames, 0.1),
    actionToRepeat = cc.Animate.create(animation),
    action = cc.RepeatForever.create(actionToRepeat);
```